Textjoin with multiple conditions
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_jOn0vyv6osaoppeU9TXX1boOlZbnoCFy3eWsddP7uc/edit?usp=sharing
I am using the below formula but the result is from one condition but I need to check from multiple columns.
=TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, IF(($A$7=D2)+($C$7=D2)+($E$7=D2)+($G$7=D2), $B$7, ""))
The above formula is working but only checking one column.
The formula must check multiple columns as mentioned in the below formula..
=TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, IF(($A$7=D2)+($C$7=D2)+($E$7=D2)+($G$7=D2), $B$7,$D$7,$F$7,$H$7, ""))
Please help to resolve this formula
Regards,

Here's another solution:
=ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(", ",TOCOL(IF(A7:G7=D2,B7:H7,),1))) 


Perfect answer... Thank you so much...


You may try:
=let(data_,wraprows(tocol(A7:H),2),
 textjoin(", ",1,ifna(filter(choosecols(data_,2),choosecols(data_,1)=D2))))



Amazing... Thank you so much for quick and correct reply dear rockinfreakshow.

Could you please check the Tab "New", I need to display the Columns 'All Models' instead of Columns Certificate #... in the Column BE...    Please help..
